# Удалить пустые строки из текста

Tags: python, python-3.x, текст

Есть несколько строк:

```
#920: ASP
#900: ^Ta^B08
#200: ^AСПЕЦИФИКА ПРЕПОДАВАНИЯ ФИЛОСОФИИ В СОВРЕМЕННОМ ТЕХНИЧЕСКОМ ВУЗЕ: МЕТОДОЛОГИЧЕСКИЕ ВОЗМОЖНОСТИ ПРАГМАТИЗМА
#700: ^310000633^AПятилетова^BЛ. В.
#463: ^CИсторические, философские, политические и юридические науки, культурология и искусствоведение. Вопросы теории и практики^J2015^GИздательство Грамота^DТамбов^S160-162^HN 1 (151)
#1105: Статья в журнале

#963: ^I1997-292X
*****
#920: ASP
#900: ^Ta^B08
#200: ^AСпецифика преподавания философии в современном техническом вузе: педагогические эффекты прагматизма (на примере учебной темы "Мировоззрение: виды, специфика, функции")
#700: ^310000633^AПятилетова^BЛ. В.
#701: ^AМыльников^BМ. М.
#463: ^CГуманитарные научные исследования^J2014^GМеждународный научно-инновационный центр^DМосква^S53-58^HN 836
#1105: Статья в журнале
#963: ^I2225-3157

*****
```

Хотелось бы удалить все пустые строки. Итог:

```
#920: ASP
#900: ^Ta^B08
#200: ^AСПЕЦИФИКА ПРЕПОДАВАНИЯ ФИЛОСОФИИ В СОВРЕМЕННОМ ТЕХНИЧЕСКОМ ВУЗЕ: МЕТОДОЛОГИЧЕСКИЕ ВОЗМОЖНОСТИ ПРАГМАТИЗМА
#700: ^310000633^AПятилетова^BЛ. В.
#463: ^CИсторические, философские, политические и юридические науки, культурология и искусствоведение. Вопросы теории и практики^J2015^GИздательство Грамота^DТамбов^S160-162^HN 1 (151)
#1105: Статья в журнале    
#963: ^I1997-292X
*****
#920: ASP
#900: ^Ta^B08
#200: ^AСпецифика преподавания философии в современном техническом вузе: педагогические эффекты прагматизма (на примере учебной темы "Мировоззрение: виды, специфика, функции")
#700: ^310000633^AПятилетова^BЛ. В.
#701: ^AМыльников^BМ. М.
#463: ^CГуманитарные научные исследования^J2014^GМеждународный научно-инновационный центр^DМосква^S53-58^HN 836
#1105: Статья в журнале
#963: ^I2225-3157   
*****
```

Пыталась разбить строку и удалить все пробелы, но пустые строки все равно остаются:

```
zx = z.split(',')
while '' in zx:
    zx.remove('')
```

Comment: а почему сплит по запятой?

Comment: Наверное, потому что я - бестолочь)))

Comment: Не, не говорите так. Можно было сделать сплит по '\n', удалить из списка пустые элементы (это те, что на пустые строки попали) и после собрать обратно текст. т.е. что-то вроде такого `'\n'.join(filter(None, text.splitlines()))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно было посмотреть на структуру текста через `print(repr(text))`:

```
"#920: ASP\n#900: ^Ta^B08\n ... #1105: Статья в журнале\n\n#963: ^I1997-292X\n*****\n..."
```

Тогда бы вы заметили, что там, где присутствуют пустые строки, есть 2 подряд идущих символа переноса строки `\n`, а в других местах только один символ.

Значит, чтобы убрать пустые строки, нужно в парах убрать один `\n`.

Код:

```
text = """\
#920: ASP
#900: ^Ta^B08

...

*****
"""

new_text = text.replace('\n\n', '\n')
print(new_text)
```

Результат:

```
#920: ASP
#900: ^Ta^B08
#200: ^AСПЕЦИФИКА ПРЕПОДАВАНИЯ ФИЛОСОФИИ В СОВРЕМЕННОМ ТЕХНИЧЕСКОМ ВУЗЕ: МЕТОДОЛОГИЧЕСКИЕ ВОЗМОЖНОСТИ ПРАГМАТИЗМА
#700: ^310000633^AПятилетова^BЛ. В.
#463: ^CИсторические, философские, политические и юридические науки, культурология и искусствоведение. Вопросы теории и практики^J2015^GИздательство Грамота^DТамбов^S160-162^HN 1 (151)
#1105: Статья в журнале
#963: ^I1997-292X
*****
#920: ASP
#900: ^Ta^B08
#200: ^AСпецифика преподавания философии в современном техническом вузе: педагогические эффекты прагматизма (на примере учебной темы "Мировоззрение: виды, специфика, функции")
#700: ^310000633^AПятилетова^BЛ. В.
#701: ^AМыльников^BМ. М.
#463: ^CГуманитарные научные исследования^J2014^GМеждународный научно-инновационный центр^DМосква^S53-58^HN 836
#1105: Статья в журнале
#963: ^I2225-3157
*****
```

Comment: Как всегда все идеально сработало!!! Спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
str_whith_space = """
    example line 1

    example line 2
    example line 3

    example line 4"""

new_str = '\n'.join(el.strip() for el in str_whith_space.split('\n') if el.strip())
print(new_str)
```

""" 
example line 1 
example line 2 
example line 3 
example line 4 
"""

Answer (score 0):

Как один из вариантов докину:

```py
text = """#920: ASP
#900: ^Ta^B08
#200: ^AСПЕЦИФИКА ПРЕПОДАВАНИЯ ФИЛОСОФИИ В СОВРЕМЕННОМ ТЕХНИЧЕСКОМ ВУЗЕ
#700: ^310000633^AПятилетова^BЛ. В.
#463: ^CИсторические, философские. ^J2015^GИздательство Грамота^DТамбов^S160-162^HN 1 (151)
#1105: Статья в журнале

#963: ^I1997-292X
*****
#920: ASP
#900: ^Ta^B08
#200: ^AСпецифика преподавания философии в современном техническом вузе
#700: ^310000633^AПятилетова^BЛ. В.
#701: ^AМыльников^BМ. М.
#463: ^CГуманитарные научные исследования^J2014^G^DМосква^S53-58^HN 836
#1105: Статья в журнале
#963: ^I2225-3157

*****"""

print('\n'.join(filter(bool, text.split('\n'))))
```

если предположить, что текст может быть с рандомным разделителем строк, как то `\r` для MAC, `\r\n` для Windows, ну и `\n` - Linux то можно воспользоваться библиотекой `re`

```py
import re
print('\n'.join(filter(bool, re.split(r'[\r\n]+', text))))
```